# create a directory to save recorded files on iphone using objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, directory

I am letting user record audio from mic to .acc file

at the moment they are saved to default app document folder

in plist i enabled "supports opening documents in place"

Now in iPhones File App i can see my apps folder in Documents and also see and listen to the recorded .acc file

great... but...

Now the user can also see and then edit / mess with ini files and other files i dont really want them o see or edit etc...

So now this isnt a good solution.

So where do i save recorded audio so that users can still see them, find them on their phone, listen and share them with friends (without being to see the apps other files)?

Answer (score 1):

For any files that don't need to change, just keep them as resources in your app bundle and load them from there at runtime.

For files that are generated at runtime (not at build-time) or config files that change, which you don't want to be exposed, put them in Application Support instead of in Documents.

In Objective-C:

```
NSArray * appSupportURLs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                              inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
```

In Swift:

```
let appSupportURLs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, 
                                               in: .userDomainMask)
```

This Apple Developer video pretty much covers it: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/

Comment: That seems an optioin but my XCode is generated by Game Maker Studio I dont actually know much Xcode/Swift etc..  and just learning objective C.